# Extract specific word matching the pattern

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, stringr, vcf-variant-call-format

I have data frame with a column:

`nf1$Info = AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.026e+00;ClippingRankSum=-1.026e+00;DP=4;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=28.25;MQRankSum=-1.026e+00;QD=10.18;ReadPosRankSum=1.03;SOR=0.693`

I'm trying to extract a specific value from this column.

For e.g. I'm interested in "MQRankSum" and  I used:

```
str_extract(nf1$Info,"[MQRankSum]+=[:punct:]+[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+")
```

It returns value for *BaseQRankSum* instead of *MQRankSum*.

Comment: Why wrap char sequences with  `[...]`? Remove them. `"MQRankSum=[^;]+"`

Comment: Thanks you. it worked.

Comment: Is this from a vcf file? How did you read the file into R? Maybe use vcfR package?

Comment: This is an annotated vcf file. I prefer filtering the .txt file. I am aware of the vcfR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including characters into square brackets creates a character class matching any of the defined characters, so `[yes]+` matches `yyyyyyyyy`, `eyyyyss`, etc.

What you want to do is to match a  word `MQRankSum`, `=`, and then any chars other than `;`:

```
str_extract(nf1$Info,"MQRankSum=[^;]+")
```

If you want to exlcude `MQRankSum=` from the match, use a lookbehind:

```
str_extract(nf1$Info,"(?<=MQRankSum=)[^;]+")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<=MQRankSum=)` positive lookbehind will make sure there is `MQRankSum=` text immediately to the left of the current location, and only after that will match 1 or more chars other than `;`.

Comment: Really helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

We could split *INFO* column into multiple columns then extract desired column:

```
# dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3,
                  info = c("AC=1;AF=0.500;MQRankSum=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.026e+00;ClippingRankSum=-1.026e+00;",
                           "AC=1;AF=0.500;MQRankSum=2;ClippingRankSum=-1.026e+00;DP=4;",
                           "AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.026e+00;"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# split INFO into seperate columns
df1_info <- data.table::rbindlist(
  lapply(strsplit(df1$info, ";|="), function(i)
    setNames(data.frame(t(as.numeric(i[ c(FALSE, TRUE) ]))), i[ c(TRUE, FALSE) ])
    ),
  fill = TRUE)

df1_info
#    AC  AF MQRankSum BaseQRankSum ClippingRankSum DP AN
# 1:  1 0.5         2       -1.026          -1.026 NA NA
# 2:  1 0.5         2           NA          -1.026  4 NA
# 3: NA  NA        NA       -1.026              NA NA  2

# extract required column 
df1_info$BaseQRankSum
# [1] -1.026     NA -1.026
```

---

VCF **INFO** [standard](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/1268/what-is-a-vcf-and-how-should-i-interpret-it):

> Various site-level annotations.  The annotations contained in the INFO
>   field are represented as tag-value pairs, where the tag and value are
>   separated by an equal sign, ie =, and pairs are separated by colons,
>   ie ; as in this example:
>   `MQ=99.00;MQ0=0;QD=17.94`.

Comment: Very informative. From the above example I mentioned where I have more values in the Info column than you mentioned in you example, how should i split that in to separate column. Eg Info:                                                                                   "AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.026e+00;ClippingRankSum=-1.026e+00;DP=4;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=28.25;MQRankSum=-1.026e+00;QD=10.18;ReadPosRankSum=1.03;SOR=0.693"

Comment: @beginner above code should work with any number of values. If it doesn't please edit your post and provide reproducible example: `dput(head(nf1$Info))`